# How to communicate with ups with a serial port?

Tags: usb, drivers, power-supply, serial-port, ups

I have this offbrand chinese ups that I want to plug in my computer, the manual state that it has a "COM port" but nothing else about it, it doesn't provide a driver neither.

Plugging the UPS with a usb type B to A cable to my computer detect it as an "HID-compliant device" and doesn't seem to find any driver for it.

[image: Device manager screenshot]

Is there anyway to get information from the UPS like the charge left, so I can make a program that gently shutdown the computer before power goes off ?

**Edit**

This tool http://networkupstools.org seems to detect my UPS

**Edit 2**

Can't get NUT to work with my ups, manually installing libusb didn't work neither

**Edit 3**

rdesc : http://sprunge.us/WEZV

lsusb : http://sprunge.us/hNiM

Comment: Right-click on the device and select **Properties** -> **Details** tab, then from the drop-down list show **Hardware IDs** and then **Compatible IDs**. If you search for these strings, you may get lucky.

Comment: Compatible IDs is empty, and hardware ids give my a bunch of strings, how can I search those ?
Also this was on the "HID-compliant device", "USB input device" give me different results, which one should I work with ?

Comment: Search for each string in turn, preferably in double quotes. I would try the USB device first, but try the other if you don't find anything.

Comment: I found this page http://networkupstools.org/stable-hcl.html with a lot of generic drivers but can't seem to find the appropriate one

Comment: The `VEN` part of the ID string should indicate the manufacturer.

Comment: There is no VEN part in the string, as I said before this is a cheap offbrand UPS, googling the reference on the manual returns no result

Comment: If it's HID compliant, it should have a HID descriptor, so it tells you the format of data you can send to it, and the format of data you receive. Your OS seems to be Windows, but I don't know how to access the HID descriptor on Windows, only on Linux.

Comment: I have no other suggestions. You'll need to contact wherever you bought the unit - support software should have been delivered with it.

Comment: @AFH No support software came with the unit, i'm sure even the vendor doesn't provide one

Comment: @dirkt Can you tell me how to do it on linux ? I could try it on a virtual machine

Comment: I'm afraid you're on your own. For myself, I wouldn't use an unbranded UPS, because I'd be concerned about the safety standards and the possibility of fire.

Comment: Does the UPS have a physical serial interface (such as a DB9 connector)? If not, the COM port that the manual refers to might be a virtual serial port, so there's likely a driver out there that exposes it.

Comment: @AFH yes you're right, an unbranded UPS isn't something I should rely on. But I would find this a good reverse engineering exercise,  if only I could communicate with this device

Comment: @Brian Nope, only usb type B connector, which after googling seems to be a "serial to usb adapter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer:

A HID-compliant device should have a HID descriptor, which describes the valid format(s) of data to and from the device.

On Linux, you can access the HID descriptor in the following way:

Look at the new lines in `dmesg` that appear after you plug in the device. This will tell you if the Linux kernel also recognizes it as a HID device, and the bus number, as well as the vendor and device id.

If it isn't already mounted, do

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

as root. Then `/sys/kernel/debug/hid/<dev>/rdesc` will contain the HID descriptor, where `<dev>` is a device identifier containing the bus number, vendor and device id, and an additional number.

Look at the contents of the descriptor with `cat '/sys/kernel/debug/hid/<dev>/rdesc'`, and edit the question to include the contents (or place it in a pastebin etc., and edit the question with a link).

`lsusb` and `lsusb -v -d xxxx:yyyy` (where `xxxx:yyyy` is the vendor and device id) will also give information that may help in determining how to communicate with the device.

**Edit**

That's a funny way to use HID USB: The HID descriptor says you can read and write chunks of 8 byte length, with application-specific (non-standard) purpose, and indeed, the [blazer_usb](https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/blob/master/drivers/blazer_usb.c) driver code in NUT exactly does that, simulating a serial USB via 8 byte chunks. Totally crazy.

[Here](http://www.evilbox.ro/linux/how-to-monitor-mustek-powermust-2012-ups-with-ubuntu-server-14/) is a description how to make it work under Ubuntu, apparently there are several gotchas. The communication protocol for the serial interface proper is described [here](http://networkupstools.org/protocols/megatec.html).

If you still have trouble making it work under Linux, have a look at `usbmon` to debug what isn't working.

No idea what do for a windows driver, unless you take the source and write one yourself.

Comment: Well thank you, might take my first step into writing drivers.